# Wordpress usermeta from db returns null

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Hi im trying to get some custom content from the database. I tryed in phpMyadmin:

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'company'
```

Which returns the correct content.

Im now trying to get the content in my plugin. But its returning null

```
global $wpdb;
$companys = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'company'");
var_dump($companys);
```

Im new to sql, and googled for hours, but with no result...

Comment: This looks correct to me. How are sure that the code is actually being executed? Try preceding the code with echo 'before sql'. Also, try using a simpler sql command like 'show tables' to see that a sql command actually works from this location. Where are you running this code from -functions.php?

Comment: Found the error, i was outside the function (the code example, is simplyfied). So i got null... That is what you get from working at night, doh! This morning its clear to me... now i'm using Chandra Kumar's example. And return this as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `DISTINCT` to your SQL query, something like:

```
global $wpdb;
$companys = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'company'" );
var_dump($companys);
```

Comment: See comment in above post :)